# Getting Error During Updation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
update refShippingTypes set ([Code],[Name],[Notes]) Values (N'AUDELIVERY',N'Ekart AU Delivery',N'EKart') where ShippingTypeId=50
```

When I am running this query getting this error
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '('.

Anyone, please tell why I am getting an error. Still, I am thinking this is a too simple script but where I am mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Syntax is wrong. It must be:

```
update refShippingTypes 
     set [Code] = N'AUDELIVERY' ,[Name] = N'Ekart AU Delivery',[Notes]= N'EKart' 
     where ShippingTypeId=50
```

Comment: @Taylor No it isn't read [here about the Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Is it feasible when we need to update multiple row record? In this case what approach we will follow?

Comment: @Taylor Yes it is. But only with multiple statements

Comment: Suppose we have to update 1000 row records, In this case, writing 1000 times same update statements is it not redundancy of code?

Comment: @Taylor, Do you use plain SQL or a script for the update?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177990/discussion-between-taylor-and-jens).

Answer (score 1):

Try below: it is not possible to update like insert statement

```
update refShippingTypes set [Code]='AUDELIVERY',[Name]='Ekart AU Delivery', 
 [Notes]='EKart' 
where ShippingTypeId=50
```

Comment: no, that's a wrong syntax for update, you've update like given answers

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following query:

```
UPDATE refShippingTypes SET Code=N'AUDELIVERY', Name=N'Ekart AU Delivery', Notes=N'EKart' WHERE ShippingTypeId=50
```

Hope that helps you!

Comment: It would be nice to explain it a little bit